# How to run net 3.1 tests with .net 5 sdk installed

Tags: c#, unit-testing, .net-core, .net-5, .net-core-3.1

I have a .NET Core 3.1 console application and test projects. I only have .NET 5 SDK installed on my machine however, using VS Code, when I try to run the tests I get the error

```
"**Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.ObjectModel.TestPlatformException: Testhost process exited with error: It was not possible to find any compatible framework version
The framework 'Microsoft.NETCore.App', version '3.1.0' was not found**"
```

I can't install .Net Core 3.1 on my machine as it is a hustle getting admin privileges since it is a corporate work laptop. However, I have installed the binaries for .NET Core 3.1 using the following instructions:

- Navigate to:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/install/windows?tabs=net50#download-and-manually-install

to see if this would work but I still get the same error. Building the actual console apps works fine (even without the .net 3.1 binaries) but I am struggling to run the test projects. Would anyone know the best way to run my .NET Core 3.1 tests whilst I have .NET 5 sdk installed?

Comment: Just as a quick hint: have you tried to change your tests to use NET5? Or Build with two frameworks [<TargetFrameworks>netcore3.1;net5.0</TargetFrameworks>](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/standard/frameworks) and then run your tests in the net5 context if installed.

Comment: @Martin , yes I have tried and I get the same error as above.  Even if I switch to just using .net 5 I get the error "**`Test run detected DLL(s) which were built for different framework and platform versions. Following DLL(s) do not match current settings, which are .NETCoreApp,Version=v5.0 framework and X64 platform.
CommonServices.Tests.dll is built for Framework .NETCoreApp,Version=v3.1 and Platform AnyCPU.
Go to https://aka.ms/tp/vstest/multitargetingdoc?view=vs-2019 for more details on managing these settings.**`" This doesnt help either....